# Convert Excel function or VBA for use in Word macros

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I use the following function or VBA in Excel to convert numbers to letters.
This code works well in Excel.

```
Global AlphaNumeric1(0 To 19) As String
Global AlphaNumeric2(1 To 9) As String
Global AlphaNumeric3(1 To 9) As String 
Sub alphaset()
   Dim i%
   AlphaNumeric1(0) = "Zero"
   AlphaNumeric1(1) = "One"
.
.
.
   AlphaNumeric1(19) = "Nineteen"
      
   AlphaNumeric2(1) = "Ten "
.
.
.
   AlphaNumeric2(9) = "Ninety "
   
   AlphaNumeric3(1) = "One hundred"
.
.
.
   AlphaNumeric3(9) = "nine hundred"       
End Sub
Function Digit2Word(Number As String) As String   
   alphaset
    Dim No As Currency, N As String
    On Error GoTo Digit2Worderror
    No = CCur(Number)
    N = CStr(No)
    Select Case Len(N)
        Case 1 To 3:
                If N < 20 Then
                    Digit2Word= AlphaNumeric1(N)
                ElseIf N < 100 Then
                    If N Mod 10 = 0 Then
                        Digit2Word= AlphaNumeric2(N \ 10)
                    Else
                        Digit2Word= AlphaNumeric2(N \ 10) & " and " & Digit2Word(N Mod 10)
                    End If
                ElseIf N < 1000 Then
                    If N Mod 100 = 0 Then
                        Digit2Word= AlphaNumeric3(N \ 100)
                    Else
                        Digit2Word= AlphaNumeric3(N \ 100) & " and " & Digit2Word(N Mod 100)
                    End If
                End If
        Case 4 To 6:
                If (Right(N, 3)) = 0 Then
                   Digit2Word= Digit2Word(Left(N, Len(N) - 3)) & " Thousand  "
                Else
                    Digit2Word= Digit2Word(Left(N, Len(N) - 3)) & " Thousand and " & Digit2Word(Right(N, 3))
                End If
        Case 7 To 9:
                If (Right(N, 6)) = 0 Then
                   Digit2Word= Digit2Word(Left(N, Len(N) - 6)) & " Million "
                Else
                    Digit2Word= Digit2Word(Left(N, Len(N) - 6)) & " Million and " & Digit2Word(Right(N, 6))
                End If
        Case Else:
                If (Right(N, 9)) = 0 Then
                   Digit2Word= Digit2Word(Left(N, Len(N) - 9)) & " Billion "
                Else
                    Digit2Word= Digit2Word(Left(N, Len(N) - 9)) & " Billion and " & Digit2Word(Right(N, 9))
                End If
    End Select
    Exit Function
Digit2Worderror:
    Digit2Word= "#Error"
End Function
```

How can I convert this VBA to use in Word by running Macro? (For example, select the number that the mouse pointer is on and turn it into letters. Running macros in Word and Without linking to Excel)

Comment: Don't understand your question: as you don't use any Excel specific functions, this code works exactly the same in Word VBA.

Comment: @ba haran checkout this [How To Convert Number To Words In Word Document?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/5497-word-convert-number-to-words.html)